# Remember Device In AWS Cognito For Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am developing an Android app where all my users who logged inside my application should be remembered. More specifically, get their Device Key register in their user profile. The problem here is my currSignedDevice shows “null” as shown below and when I try to remember it, It is not being remembered.

I am using AWS Cognito and followed their documentation here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/. I set my device settings in Cognito and implemented with code below.

[image]

```
fun getSignInUserDeviceDetails(user: String?):Boolean {
    var currSignedDevice = userPool.getUser (user).thisDevice();
    println("device is "+ currSignedDevice +"\t")
    var  changeDeviceSettingsHandler: GenericHandler = object : GenericHandler {
         override fun onSuccess() {
             // Device status successfully changed
             println("device remembered successfully")
         }

         override fun onFailure(exception: java.lang.Exception) {
             // Probe exception for the cause of the failure
             println("failure in remember device")
         }
     }

    currSignedDevice?.rememberThisDevice(changeDeviceSettingsHandler)
    return true
}
```

Called this function in my loginfragment after the valid authentication.

```
login.setOnClickListener {
    val email = email.text.toString()
    val password = password.text.toString()

    if (email.trim().isEmpty()) {
        toastError("Enter an email.")
        return@setOnClickListener
    }

    if (password.trim().isEmpty()) {
        toastError("Enter a password.")
        return@setOnClickListener
    }
    emailVal = email.toLowerCase()
    passwordVal = password
    signInDialog?.show()
    activity?.let {
        (it as MainActivity).setDialog50PercentWidth(signInDialog)
    }
    viewModel.authenticate(email, password, confirmUserHandler)
    AWSClient.instance.getSignInUserDeviceDetails(emailVal)
}
```

The problem here is my currSignedDevice shows “null” as shown below in the figure and when I try to remember it, It is not being remembered. This is also not going inside of success or failure. It’s directly jumping out from that block.

```
fun getSignInUserDeviceDetails(user: String?):Boolean {
    var  currSignedDevice = userPool.getUser (user).thisDevice();
    println("device is "+ currSignedDevice +"\t") // gives my currSignedDevice as NULL when I debug
     var  changeDeviceSettingsHandler: GenericHandler = object : GenericHandler {
             override fun onSuccess() {
                 println("device remembered successfully")
             }
             override fun onFailure(exception: java.lang.Exception) {
                 // Probe exception for the cause of the failure
                 println("failure in remeber device")
             }
         }
    currSignedDevice.rememberThisDevice(changeDeviceSettingsHandler)
    return true
}
```